# Using multithreading to send multiple emails

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net, .net-5

I'm trying to send any number of emails in the shortest amount of time using .NET 5.0?

I've been playing with something like the following but I am not sure if it is optimal or even correct as there are a number of elements I don't understand.

```
public async Task SendEmailAsync(string subject, string htmlMessage,
    IEnumerable<string> recipients, string? attachment)
{
    using SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new(10, 10);
    await Task.WhenAll(recipients.Select(async recipient =>
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();

        try
        {
            return SendEmailAsync(subject, htmlMessage, recipient, attachment);
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }));
}
```

Can someone clarify if this is correct, or let me know if they know a better approach?

Comment: To the best of your knowledge, does the code work as intended? If not, then the post is [off-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) - note that the help page states "_If you are looking for feedback on a specific **working** piece of code...then you are in the right place!_"

Comment: What makes you think the email client can handle parallel requests? I’d assume they are all just queued up and processed sequentially there anyway.

Comment: @Aganju: Most of the time it takes to send an email is spent waiting for the server to respond. It would be stupid to queue them all up. At any rate, I'm not responsible for if mail server designers make stupid designs. I'm just responsible that my code doesn't have a stupid design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, this code doesn't respect the semaphore. It just send all emails without concurrency degree limiting by semaphore. Because `return SendEmailAsync` returns right after `Task` object is received not the method finished, then semaphore is released immediately. Thus semaphore thottles only requests creation which I assume is fast.

The fix is `await` in `try` clause.

```cs
public async Task SendEmailAsync(string subject, string htmlMessage,
    IEnumerable<string> recipients, string? attachment)
{
    using SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new(10);
    await Task.WhenAll(recipients.Select(recipient =>
        SendEmailAsync(subject, htmlMessage, recipient, attachment, semaphore)));
}

private async Task SendEmailAsync(string subject, string htmlMessage,
    string recipient, string? attachment, SemaphoreSlim semaphore)
{
    await semaphore.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        await SendEmailAsync(subject, htmlMessage, recipient, attachment);
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

The rest part of the code looks fine for me. Probably I can only suggest to use OOP to encapsulate data for bulk emailing into some class. It would make furure code improvements easier.

Comment: Would this not be the same as adding the `await` keyword before calling `SendEmailAsync()` in my code?

Comment: @JonathanWood probably but you can't return `void` in `Select`, right? I'm not strong in lambdas syntax without IDE, just wrote the answer from mobile. Anyway, the method-like approach isn't slower than lambda in performance.

Comment: @JonathanWood try changing `return` to `await`. If it will compile successful then it's done.

Comment: Yes, that seems to work. A lambda doesn't necessarily return anything.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach can result in a huge number of tasks active at any given time, each of them representing load on the machine's IO resources. You need a way to limit the number of tasks.

Your approach also abuses the Select() call pretty badly. If nothing else, it makes the code very hard to read.

Here is a demonstration using a fixed number of tasks to simulate sending an email to 1000 recipients. Note that access to the shared Queue<> does not need to be synchronized in this example, but it may be needed depending on the API call used in practice, so I added synchronization. A simple lock {} suffices.

```
private static readonly Random random = new Random();
private static readonly Queue<string> recipients = new Queue<string>();

protected override async Task Run()
{
    for  (int i = 1; i <= 1000; ++i)
    {
        recipients.Enqueue($"recipient_{i:00000}@emaildomain.com");
    }

    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 50; ++i)
    {
        tasks.Add(SendEmails($"Task {i:00000}"));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

private static async Task SendEmails(string taskName)
{
    for (; ;)
    {
        string recipient;

        lock (recipients)
        {
            if (recipients.Count == 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            recipient = recipients.Dequeue();
        }

        Debug.WriteLine($"{taskName}: Sending to {recipient}...");
        await SendEmailAsync(recipient);
        Debug.WriteLine($"{taskName}: Sending to {recipient} complete");
    }

    Debug.WriteLine($"{taskName}: No more recipients; quitting");
}

private static async Task SendEmailAsync(string recipient)
{
    // Simulate sending an email with random network latency.
    await Task.Delay(random.Next(100, 2000));
}
```

Comment: `Queue<string>` isn't thread-safe and might be damaged if async calls performed not on single-threaded `SynchronizationContext`. _everything happens on one thread_ I'm not sure if that's true.

Comment: @aepot good point. Everything happens in one thread in this example, but you are correct that continuations may be scheduled on different threads depending on how the API was implemented. I'll edit to add a lock.

Comment: `ConcurrentQueue` may be faster than `lock`. Also you may update the text.

Comment: @aepot it probly doesn't matter. The queue is just there to support the task concurrency example I threw together. OP may not go that route. The important part is how to limit the number pf tasks without using a SemaphoreSlim.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I created a project from it and tested it out. In the end (and aside from the queue concurrency issue), it felt a little complex. With @aepot's approach, it seems to be working right by changing only one keyword.

Comment: Ok, but I'm not sure that avoiding the semaphore makes the code more efficient. Anyway I like the solution. Will make some benchmarks to ensure.

Comment: @aepot: That comment mentioned you but was not directed at you, as evidenced by the fact that I marked your answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: I did some simple bench marking. OP's approach does not scale linearly with larger numbers of recipients, where as mine appears to be very linear. However, I was only able to make this comparison in a reasonable amount of time by using millions of recipients and by completely removing the delay. In the real world, performance will be affected overwhelmingly by email sending elapsed time. It would take hours to benchmark. With 10000 recipients and 50ms delay, performance is identical.